# rpc.svcgssd fails

Tags: server, configuration, nfs

I have the following degraded service on "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS":

```
Jun 21 10:39:14 server rpc.svcgssd[1301170]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in gss_acquire_cred(): GSS_S_NO_CRED (No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible) - No >
Jun 21 10:39:14 server rpc.svcgssd[1301170]: unable to obtain root (machine) credentials
Jun 21 10:39:14 server rpc.svcgssd[1301170]: do you have a keytab entry for nfs/<your.host>@<YOUR.REALM> in/etc/krb5.keytab?
Jun 21 10:39:14 server systemd[1]: rpc-svcgssd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 21 10:39:14 server systemd[1]: rpc-svcgssd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have no entries in the keytab, and I cannot set anything.

```
libnfs-utils/jammy,now 4.0.0-1build2 amd64 [installed]
libnfs13/jammy,now 4.0.0-1build2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnfsidmap1/jammy-updates,now 1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nfs-common/jammy-updates,now 1:2.6.1-1ubuntu1.2 amd64 [installed]
```

I have running from ideas, could you please help me?

Regards HB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have search more, looks like only one resolution for me.

https://forge.univention.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46587

https://help.univention.com/t/failed-rpc-security-service-for-nfs-server-after-4-3-upgrade/8196/8

systemctl stop rpc-svcgssd.service

systemctl disable rpc-svcgssd.service

systemctl mask rpc-svcgssd.service